# Are there examples of food products that appear more attractive in low-CRI lighting?

Tags: lighting, color-correction, food-photography

I am sure shops generally choose lighting carefully to make products appear the most attractive. And I know that low-CRI often make some products appear dull and unattractive. But is high CRI always better? Could it be that the light source chosen for red sliced meat is actually intentionally chosen to have little light in the green spectrum, so that it will appear more red than brown?

Do you know of such examples of intentionally choosing light sources with unnatural spectral distribution and/or low CRI to make something appear more attractive?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about lighting grocery shops, not photographs

Comment: Not exclusively about lighting in a grocery shop. It could be lighting of a raw steak about to be photographed for the cover of a book. In any case, I expect photographers to know much about how lighting affect appearance and I expect the answer to such a question to be of interest to many photographers, so IMO it certainly fits this forum.

Comment: If you have a question about lighting for a steak for a cover of a book, ask that question.

Comment: Asking that very specific question will give a very specific answer. I am not looking to take a photo of a steak. I am looking to improve my understanding of lighting which will make me a better photographer. This certainly is about photography.

Comment: I think what @mattdm is trying to say is, if you're asking about how to light food for photographic purposes and how that lighting might differ from non-photographic display food lighting, ask that question. Rather than ask a question that _might_ have photographic purposes at Photo.SE, ask a photographic question that _might also_ have non-photographic purposes.

Comment: What does "fx" mean in the title? What is CRI?

Comment: Fx means "for example". I thought this was standard English?

Comment: Some healthy and tasty foods are actually strongly flourescent - everything that contains turmeric, some anthocyanin containing foods, drinks containing quinine... these could benefit from a badly "corrected" light source having overly strong short-blue/UV content...

Comment: @MadsSkjern here, most people will wonder if you are talking about "special effects food" or "full frame food".

Comment: @MadsSkjern No, that's definitely not standard English. It's not even widespread slang. In the context of photography, I would have assumed "fx" to mean "effects", as in special effects. (See [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fx))

Comment: I think this should be discussed here: https://ell.stackexchange.com/ ;)

Comment: yes, such photographers often used gel filters on flashes to dial in whatever made it "look best"; highly subjective, but certainly not neutral lighting. These days it's more likely they use a high CRI light to capture all the detail possible, then digitally manipulate the image to suit a certain look/feel.

Comment: Because English is *awesome* the actual standard abbreviation for "for example" is in fact *e.g.*

Comment: @dandavis Sounds like a good start on an answer!

Comment: Thanks for correcting the title and my english :) I was totally unaware of the misunderstanding it caused!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appearance can indeed be enhanced at the cost of CRI. There is a video showing how color appearance can create different effects by altering spectral characteristics of the illuminant and shows various items, including some colorful vegetables, with differing spectral characteristics. Check out the examples around 5:40 in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CfxcbkM6ZHY).

The main area where different lighting is used to create different effects is the IES TM-30 work. More technical details are discussed [here](https://www.energy.gov/eere/ssl/tm-30-frequently-asked-questions) and [here](https://www.energy.gov/sites/prod/files/2015/12/f27/tm-30_fact-sheet.pdf).

There is also [this research](https://www.osapublishing.org/DirectPDFAccess/2237852B-0EAA-0754-6FBAE004A9DBDBD5_335402/oe-24-1-573.pdf?da=1&id=335402&seq=0&mobile=no) that studies how to optimize for higher perceived color saturation. In particular, GAI (Gamut Area Index) is especially applicable to retail displays.

*But the definition of color rendering by the CRI is limited, and many research papers have already shown that high CRI alone is not enough to reflect the true color of the products in some special applications, e.g. retails/shops, where the subjective characteristics such as attractiveness and preferences would be more useful. Progresses have been made in recent years to develop new color quality metrics. Among many metrics, gamut area index (GAI) can be a useful supplement to the well-established CRI in ensuring color saturation and satisfactory perception of the object color. A light source which has enhanced chromatic saturation (chroma) can serve to increase
the visual clarity...*